# Colorbox reload parent page on close

Tags: jquery, colorbox

My issue is that I need a colorbox to reload the parent page on close.

This is what I have:

```
$(".example").colorbox({
    onClosed:function(){
        parent.location.reload();
    }
});
```

Colorbox loads fine, but doesn't refresh the parent page on close. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 13):

Use `window.location.reload();` or `window.location = window.location;` instead of `parent.location.reload();`

Answer (score 3):

A bit delayed, but I've got another answer. You can send the code to reload window from the target page that gets loaded in colorbox.

I was using the colorbox for login/how_it_works/faqs & few other functions. I wanted my parent page to reload only in case of 'login'. So, in response to login form, I sent the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.parent.location.reload();
</script>
```

'window' is colorbox window. I'm asking its parent (browser window) to reload.

Answer (score 1):

Or just use

```
<input type="submit" onclick="parent.location.reload()" value="Save" name="submit"/>
```

I prefer this one over Lucas's solution, because you can also easily create

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:parent.$.colorbox.close()" value="Cancel" />
```

without it reloading the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my generic colorbox-opening-function:

It can:

- Reload the page after closing
- Reload it-self (+ with some custom Ajax URL)
- Load another HTML
- IMPORTANT -> these actions happen when you MANUALLY close colorbox:

  - Setup global variables appropriately
  - $.colorbox.close();

Also:

- Focus a custom HTML element after load

The main point is, you should have (but of course if you know what you're doing) some few GLOBAL JavaScript variables and that's it.

```
function showActionForColorBox(
   _url,
   _forFocus
   ) {
   _url = fixURLWithMasterServerPrefix(_url);
   $.colorbox(
         {
            scrolling: false,
            href: _url,
            onLoad: function () {
               idColorboxAjaxIndect1.appendTo($('#cboxOverlay'));
               idColorboxAjaxIndect2.appendTo($('#cboxOverlay'));
               idColorboxAjaxIndect3.appendTo($('#cboxOverlay'));
               idColorboxAjaxIndect4.appendTo($('#cboxOverlay'));
               return;
            },
            onComplete: function () {
               if (_forFocus) {
                  var c = $('#' + _forFocus);
                  if (c.length) {
                     c.focus();
                  }
               }
               return;
            },
            onCleanup: function () {
               // TODO: ?
               return;
            },
            onClosed: function () {
               abortAllAsyncAjaxRequests();

               if (shouldReloadPageAfterColorBoxAction) {
                  shouldReloadPageAfterColorBoxAction = false; // NOTE: To be sure: Reset.
                  reloadWholePage();
               }
               else if (cbEBillsActionReloadPopup) {
                  cbEBillsActionReloadPopup = false;
                  // NOTE: WE HAVE AN OPTION TO RELOAD COLORBOX WITH CUSTOM URL !
                  showActionForColorBox((cbActionReloadPopupCustomURL !== '' ? cbActionReloadPopupCustomURL : _url));
                  cbActionReloadPopupCustomURL = '';
               }
               else if (cbShouldLoadAnotherContentAfterClosed) {
                  cbShouldLoadAnotherContentAfterClosed = false;
                  $.colorbox({ html: setupContentForcbShouldLoadAnotherContentAfterClosed });
                  setupContentForcbShouldLoadAnotherContentAfterClosed = '';
               }
               return;
            }
         }
         );

   return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){
    location.reload();
});
```

The above code is for colorbox default close (x) button.

If you have your own close button then try like this:

```
$('#id').click(function(){
    location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function __colorbox_onClose(e) {
    $.fn.colorbox.close();
    return false;
}
$.fn.colorbox.close(); - Closes colorbox manually

return false; - reloads/Autopostbac's form from which you called colorbox
```